# SQL/Python: Combine multiple entries from "linked" tables into one single comma-separated string per entry

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

I have data in 3 tables.  For each entry in tblDataDef, I have several tags (like a hashtag or category).  These tags are stored in tblDataTags, where there is an entry for each tag (D_ID is the tblDataDef ID, TAG_ID is the tblTags ID).

For example, lets assume my first entry has tags ("a", "b", "c").  The following would represent that:

```
tblDataDef| **ID=1**  

tblDataTags| ID=47, **D_ID=1**, *TAG_ID=1*  
tblDataTags| ID=48, **D_ID=1**, *TAG_ID=2*  
tblDataTags| ID=49, **D_ID=1**, *TAG_ID=3*  

tblTags| *ID=1*, TAG="a"  
tblTags| *ID=2*, TAG="b"  
tblTags| *ID=3*, TAG="c"
```

I need to create a new column/field with a comma-separated string of ALL tags associated with each ID from tblDataDef.  So the new field would be populated with "a,b,c" for the example above.  I'm doing this to populate a TreeView column in tkinter.

My current method takes a little bit of time, because it is doing thousands of queries as it iterates through the tblDataDef IDs.  Is there a faster way?  Thanks!!

**Loading tblDataDef data:**

```
def load_data():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(strConn)
    strSQL = "SELECT ID, ITEM, DESCRIP FROM tblDataDef"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(strSQL, conn)
    conn.close()
    return df
```

**Loading tags (for a single ID from tblDataDef):**

```
def load_data_tags(series):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(strConn)   
    strSQL = ("SELECT tblTags.TAG "
              "FROM tblDataTags "
              "LEFT JOIN tblTags ON tblDataTags.TAG_ID=tblTags.ID "
              f"WHERE D_ID = {series}")  
    df = pd.read_sql_query(strSQL, conn)
    conn.close()
    return df
```

**Populating tkinter's TreeView with the data:**

```
df = load_data()
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    _id = self.tree.insert("", index="end")
    self.tree.set(_id, column="ID", value=r["ID"])
    self.tree.set(_id, column="Item", value=r["ITEM"])
    self.tree.set(_id, column="Description", value=r["DESCRIP"])

    tags = load_data_tags(r["ID"])
    tags = tags["TAG"].values.tolist()
    tags = ";".join(tags)
    self.tree.set(_id, column="Tags", value=tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database engine used supports aggregate function `GROUP_CONCAT()` (supported by MySQL and sqlite3), then you can combine the two function `load_data()` and `load_data_tags()` into one:

```
def load_all_data():
    strSQL = ('SELECT dd.ID, ITEM, DESCRIP, GROUP_CONCAT(TAG) AS TAGS '
              'FROM tblDataDef dd, tblDataTags dt, tblTags t '
              'WHERE dd.ID = dt.D_ID AND dt.TAG_ID = t.ID '
              'GROUP BY dd.ID')
    df = pd.read_sql_query(strSQL, conn)
    return df
```

Then populate the result:

```
df = load_all_data()
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    _id = tree.insert('', index='end')
    tree.set(_id, column='ID', value=r['ID'])
    tree.set(_id, column='Item', value=r['ITEM'])
    tree.set(_id, column='Description', value=r['DESCRIP'])
    tree.set(_id, column='Tags', value=r['TAGS'])
```